# Correct way to write in dependency array when dispatch an action using hooks in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Considering the code snippet in the following:

```js
import * as actions from './actions'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { myAction } = actions

  const handler = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(myAction())
  }, [dispatch, myAction])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

However, if i modify the code like this without using destructing assignment:

```js
import * as actions from './actions'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handler = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(actions.myAction())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Now i do not need to include `actions.myAction` to my dependency array anymore. If i try to append into it, the eslint will prompt up a warning saying that:

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'actions.myAction'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array...

I have no idea why this happens, and which way should i follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because **actions** will be holding exactly same reference during the whole lifecycle of your app.
Hence, including it in your dependency array is simply unnecessary as already stated in ESLint warning. So it is.

You can keep using one of the below alternatives:

1.

```
import actions from './actions';

const handler = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(actions.myAction())
}, [dispatch])
```

2. 

```
import { myAction } from './actions';

const handler = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(myAction())
}, [dispatch]);
```